# How can i print first page of a pdf document in C# using Acobat Reader?

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I want to print first page of a pdf document. Now i can pring all pages of pdf document. But i need to print firsft page. I am using Acrobat Reader and my programming language is C#.

Comment: What mechanism are you currently using to print all of the document?  If you provide details of your current solution we may be able to help.

Comment: I am using Acrobat Reader to print all document. I open pdf file and print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can already print a pdf you might want to look at using iText sharp to extract the single page and then print it.

iTextsharp has a function ExtractPdfPage

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Not sure this is the most efficient way but if you can't instruct Acrobat to print one page through ole etc...